# Selecting Into Lag (Window Function) in MySQL Stored Function

Tags: mysql, window-functions, stored-functions

I am trying to automate mathematic formulas that I need to run many times over a dataset for a view page. I have used the SELECT INTO function to successfully create these values. Below is an example of code that **has** worked:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS InvLevel;
CREATE FUNCTION InvLevel(
    metric DECIMAL (65,4),
    norm DECIMAL (65,10)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(65,4)
BEGIN
    SET @InvLevel = NULL;
    SELECT
        metric * norm
        INTO @InvLevel;
    RETURN @InvLevel;

END //
```

I then call this with:

`CREATE VIEW Mainfile`

`SELECT`

`Clients, Users, Normalization, ID, Year`

`MNorm(Clients, Normalization) AS ClientsN,`

`MNorm(Users, Normalization) AS UsersN`

`FROM Dataset`

Does everything I want! I'm happy.

However, one of the important functions I need to run is a lag function--i.e. I'm interested in how clients, users, etc. has changed over time. So I wrote the following stored function:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS Pace;
CREATE FUNCTION Pace(
    metric decimal(65,4),
    id VARCHAR(20),
    year INT
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(65,4)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        metric - (LAG(metric, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year))
        INTO @paceco;
RETURN @paceco;
END //
```

That I then call as:

`Pace(Clients,ID,Year) AS ClientsP`

However, this operation only returns NULL values in ClientsP. I know it's not a question of the formula since if I directly write out the math in the create view function, I receive the correct values.

I know that I can just plug the original math into the view function but I have many metrics I will be repeating this formula on (for the next few years or so) so I would vastly prefer to automate it instead of have long, messy SQL files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SELECT you wrote is only querying an expression, not rows from any table. That is, you have no `FROM` clause to name a table. So there's no lagging row to reference.

Comment: Makes sense--how would I integrate FROM to make it functional? When I add a line "FROM database" under the INTO and then run the function in the view I get Error Code 1172 for results consisting of more than one row. If I LIMIT = 1 then I only receive NULL values.

Comment: You would need to store past results in a table.

Comment: (1) Function usage degrades your performance and is not reasonable. (2) Function does not see external objects (source table). `LAG(metric, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year)` must be provided into the function within the parameter. (3) Your code may be simplified to `CREATE FUNCTION InvLevel(metric DECIMAL (65,4), norm DECIMAL (65,10)) RETURNS DECIMAL(65,4) RETURN metric*norm;`, DELIMITER not needed too.

Comment: Akina - if function usage is not reasonable, what is a better way to automate the same window function many times in a view for different variables?